# Select between from database - select data for whole month

Tags: vb.net, date, select

I have a combobox that has items from 01-12 (months), based on selected month, data is pulled from database in datagridview. Selected value (month) is then put to label5.

Selecting between dates works fine, but how to select all days in 1 month without having to define day range for every month (that wouldn't work since some years have 29 days in february).

I've tried this (I've put 31 days to end range to cover all days in any month, but that resulted in error since Label5.text = "02" and VB.NET somehow knows that there are no 31 days in february:

```
Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT KONTO, NALOG, DUGUJE, POTRAZUJE, 
    DATPRO, OPIS 
    FROM PROMGL WHERE DATPRO between #" & Label5.Text & "/1/2014# and #" 
    & Label5.Text & "/31/2014#"
```

What can I do?

Comment: why not use a DateTimePicker so you are sure the data values are always correct?  you should also be using Parameterized queries

Comment: I only need data from whole month, picking dates would complicate thing, anyway in that case I could use two masked textboxes for dates, but I really need data to be displayed by picking month.
P.S. I found one article on Parameterized queries but it's too complicatefor me (I am a begginer in programming).

Comment: then use a NumericUpDown with a range of 1-12, but create actual dates from the result to use as parameters.  Eg: for EndDate start with a DATE of 5/1 then backup/subtract one day to get the last day of April

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `<` operator against the first day in the next month:

```
Dim month As Integer = Int32.Parse(Label5.Text)
Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT KONTO, NALOG, DUGUJE, POTRAZUJE,
  DATPRO, OPIS 
  FROM PROMGL WHERE DATPRO >= #" & month & "/1/2014# and DATPRO < #" 
  & (month + 1) & "/1/2014#"
```

Parsing the value to an integer also protects you from SQL Injection attacks. You should never use a value directly in a query without making sure that it can't corrupt it. Usually parameterised queries are used to make this easier.

Note: The code as written only works until november, you need to adjust the year also to support december.

Answer (score 2):

This should be done very carefully because it is very open to SQL Injection, so you could do something like this:

```
Dim month as Integer = 0

If Not Integer.TryParse(Label5.Text, month) Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim startDate as New DateTime(2014,month,1)
Dim endDate as DateTime = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

Dim SQLString As String = "SELECT KONTO, NALOG, DUGUJE, POTRAZUJE, 
    DATPRO, OPIS 
    FROM PROMGL WHERE DATPRO between #" & startDate.ToString("MM/d/yyy") & "# and #" 
    & endDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you so much. Who know how much I have to learn to come up with that one so fast.